# What are decals for in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

What are the Decals in the rewards section used for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Images of *StarCraft II* buildings and units with decals:

[image: Image of StarCraft II buildings and units with decals]
[image: Image of StarCraft II building with decals]

Answer (score 4):

Take a close look at your buildings, these are little graphics on them, and possibly on some of your units too.

Comment: Would you happen to have an image, so we all know where to look?

Comment: I posted some image samples for you Ivo, it was easier to find Terran but it's the same for the rest of the races too.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Starcraft.wikia.com:](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Decal)

> Decals are rewards, similar to achievements, used to signify the number of StarCraft II games a player has won. They appear on and around buildings and on at least some units.

Check the link for more specifics